# Move Zeroes in Scala

Tags: arrays, algorithm, scala

I'm working on "Move Zeroes" of leetcode with scala. https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/description/
Given an array nums, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements. You must do this in-place without making a copy of the array.

I have a solution which works well in IntelliJ but get the same Array with input while executing in Leetcode, also I'm not sure whether it is done in-place... Something wrong with my code ?

Thanks

```
def moveZeroes(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    val lengthOrig = nums.length
    val lengthFilfter = nums.filter(_ != 0).length
    var numsWithoutZero = nums.filter(_ != 0)
    var numZero = lengthOrig - lengthFilfter

    while (numZero > 0){
       numsWithoutZero = numsWithoutZero :+ 0
       numZero = numZero - 1
    }
    numsWithoutZero
}
```

And one more thing: the template code given by leetcode returns Unit type but mine returns Array.

```
def moveZeroes(nums: Array[Int]): Unit = {

}
```

Comment: given `nums = [0, 1, 0, 3, 12]`, after calling your function, `nums` should be `[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]`. Function params are val's in scala. Given this not sure how the requirement of the problem can be met..

Comment: also if we run the code that you provided the error received is TLE..(time limited exceeded)..

Comment: Array is a mutable class. So, you can mutate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with @ayush, Leetcode is explicitly asking you to use mutable states. You need to update the input array so that it contains the changes. Also, they ask you to do that in a minimal number of operations.

So, while it is *not* idiomatic Scala code, I suggest you a solution allong these lines:

```
def moveZeroes(nums: Array[Int]): Unit = {
    var i = 0
    var lastNonZeroFoundAt = 0
    while (i < nums.size) {
        if(nums(i) != 0) {
          nums(lastNonZeroFoundAt) = nums(i)
          lastNonZeroFoundAt += 1
        }
        i += 1

    i = lastNonZeroFoundAt
    while(i < nums.size) {
        nums(i) = 0
        i += 1
    }
}
```

As this is non-idomatic Scala, writing such code is not encouraged and thus, a little bit difficult to read. The C++ version that is shown in the solutions may actually be easier to read and help you to understand my code above:

```
void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
    int lastNonZeroFoundAt = 0;
    // If the current element is not 0, then we need to
    // append it just in front of last non 0 element we found. 
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        if (nums[i] != 0) {
            nums[lastNonZeroFoundAt++] = nums[i];
        }
    }
    // After we have finished processing new elements,
    // all the non-zero elements are already at beginning of array.
    // We just need to fill remaining array with 0's.
    for (int i = lastNonZeroFoundAt; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        nums[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work, cannot understand your idea.

Comment: It returns nothing

Comment: Of course! That what's asked. It *must* return `Unit`. The result is hold in a mutation of the `nums` variable.

Comment: I try to submit an empty program and also got the "time limit exceeded", Leetcode seems to have an issue with scala

Comment: Just got a message from Leetcode: _This had just been fixed. If you do encounter similar issues like this in Scala submission, please do report them. Thanks._ You should try to resubmit

Comment: It passed, I agree with @jwvh Leetcode doesn't support Scala well. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer gives TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) error in LeetCode..I do not know what the criteria is for that to occur..However i see a lot of things in your code that are not perfect .

*Pure functional programming discourages use of any mutable state and rather focuses on using `val` for everything*.

I would try it this way --

```
def moveZeroes(nums: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    val nonZero =  nums.filter(_ != 0)
    val numZero = nums.length - nonZero.length
    val zeros =  Array.fill(numZero){0}
    nonZero ++ zeros
}
```

P.S - This also gives TLE in Leetcode but still i guess in terms of being functional its better..Open for reviews though.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Your suggestion is more simple

Comment: This will not pass the test. You have to mutate the `nums` as explicitly asked. If you define `val res = nonZero ++ zeros`, then, you can call `Array.copy(res, 0, nums, 0, res.size)`